# Error ingreso de variables a función select creada SQLAlchemy - Python

Tags: python, sql, funciones, sqlalchemy

Estoy haciendo una función en Python por medio de SQLAlchemy, busco el consumo de un "select" de forma sencilla. Los datos de entrada son el nombre de la tabla junto con kwards que se usen para hacer el filtro where.

Ejemplo, el select en SQL sería:

```
select * from Pruebas where Codigo='123' and Nombre='Leche'
```

La función en Python sería:

```
my_stmt('Pruebas',Codigo='123',Nombre='leche')
```

Teniendo una tabla con la estructura:

```
      **Pruebas**
Codigo---Nombre ---Valor
'123' ---'Leche'---'5000'
```

Llevo el código de la siguiente manera:

```
import sqlalchemy
def my_stmt(TableName,**kwargs):
    table = sqlalchemy.Table(TableName, metadata, autoload=True, schema=esquema)
    stmt = lambda_stmt(lambda: select(table))
    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        col = column(key)        
        stmt = stmt.add_criteria(lambda s: s.where(col == value))
        #stmt += lambda s: s.where(col == value) ##De esta manera obtengo la misma respuesta
    return stmt
```

El consumo de la función sería:

```
x=my_stmt('pruebas',codigo='123',nombre='leche')

with engine.connect() as connection:
    results = connection.execute(x).fetchall()

print(results)
```

El log de la consola me muestra la siguiente información:

```
SELECT dbo.pruebas.codigo, dbo.pruebas.nombre, dbo.pruebas.valor
FROM dbo.pruebas
WHERE codigo = ? AND nombre = ?
('leche', 'leche')
```

Ese es el problema, 'leche' para las dos condiciones y obtengo una respuesta no deseada.

Y la impresión:

```
[]
```

La respuesta esperada sería:

```
[('123', 'leche', '5000')]
```

El log debería mostrar:

```
('123', 'leche')
```

Agradezco mucho cualquier solución o apunte, si hay alguna manera más sencilla de realizar el select de forma dinámica también agradecería la ayuda.

Comment: Todo se ve bien. Estas seguro de que es codigo que muestras es el que te muestra el log. Puede que no este actualizado.

Comment: @loki Muchas gracias por responder, sí, seguro que es lo que estoy ejecutando, esta es la respuesta exacta. 
![XHTML válido](http://imgfz.com/i/0vVSQkw.jpeg)

Comment: Cuando llamas la función la llamada con Codigo en mayúscula y la tabla está en minúsculas. Pon en minúsculas los kwargs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pude responder la duda.

Al parecer la función Lambda retorna el mismo resultado cuando está en un loop.
[Documentación](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-do-lambdas-defined-in-a-loop-with-different-values-all-return-the-same-result)

Lo resolví de la siguiente manera:

```
def my_stmt(TableName,**kwargs):
    table = sqlalchemy.Table(TableName, metadata, autoload=True, schema=esquema)
    stmt = lambda_stmt(lambda: select(table))
    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        col = column(key)
        stmt = stmt.add_criteria(lambda bound_stmt=stmt, bound_value=value: bound_stmt.where(col == bound_value))
    return stmt
```

Dejo el post que realicé en Stack Overflow en inglés. [Pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71051199/error-at-entry-variables-in-a-selects-function-created-with-sqlalchemy-python).
También dejo adjunta una respuesta que funciona correctamente:

```
stmt = select(table).where(*[getattr(table.c, k) == v for k, v in kwargs.items()])
```